# Add variable to request object in Django

Tags: python, django, variables, request

I'm trying to add the email variable to an request in Django.
I've tried

```
request.session['email'] = my_email
```

and

```
request.email = my_email
```

and none of them seem to work. How can this be done?

Comment: Those two do *completely* different things. What exactly are you trying to do? What do you mean when you say "none of them seem to work"? In what way do they not work? What happens? What doesn't happen that should?

Comment: I need to add the user email to the request.POST variable received on the server.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The server already has access to the email, via `request.user.email`.

Comment: On my website I use allauth to user authentication.. The user passes the mail and password and allauth does the login and email verification. On the mobile app, I need to call allauth functions to get the job done. So, a.e., the Login WebService calls a function on the server that builds the request on the format that allauth needs to authenticate the user. Does it make sense now? Or am I over complicating it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set is correct, try getting the email with this :

```
request.session['email']
```

Comment: And if i want to add one field to a submitted form throught POST.. is it possible? Or is it immutable?